# Button is invisible after doing ConstraintSet after signIn

Tags: java, android

I was trying to change the layout properties of the button added in my project, but after Running my project when the user is Sign Up the Confirm Password is made INVISIBLE but at the same time the Button is also INVISIBLE. Kindly help me to get out of this problem.

```java
    private void signInUser(){

        String email = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        email ="";
        password="";
        editTextConfirmPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buttonSignInSignUp.setText("Sign In");
        editTextUserName.setText("");
        editTextPassword.setText("");

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.connect(R.id.buttonSignInSignUp,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.mconstraintLayout,ConstraintSet.TOP,300);
        constraintSet.applyTo(mconstraintLayout);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that your are missing is

```
private void signInUser(){

        String email = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        email ="";
        password="";
        editTextConfirmPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buttonSignInSignUp.setText("Sign In");
        editTextUserName.setText("");
        editTextPassword.setText("");

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(mconstraintLayout); <-- This line
constraintSet.connect(R.id.buttonSignInSignUp,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.mconstraintLayout,ConstraintSet.TOP,300);
        constraintSet.applyTo(mconstraintLayout);
    }
```